# Convert string to javascript date

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have a string that I retrieve from a JSON object and I am trying to cast that to a javascript date variable as given below but its returning an Invalid date all the time. Any reasons why?

```
jsonObj["dateValue"]; //has a value: 2016-11-04T08:08:42.5780021+00:00
var dateValue = new Date(jsonObj["dateValue"]); // returns invalid date??
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrdk0de5/)

Comment: do a typeof of jsonObj["dateValue"], what is that returning?

Comment: if you do a new Date("2016-11-04T08:08:42.5780021+00:00") it shall return a valid date object, provided that its a string

Comment: its returning string when i did typeof.

Comment: Please create a snippet that reproduces the problem, because the code you posted does not give this error.

Comment: can you post the exact value of jsonObj["dateValue"]

Comment: Ok give me 2 minutes.. I'll just post some code using jsFiddle

Comment: `new Date("2016-11-04T08:08:42.5780021+00:00")` works (I got Fri Nov 04 2016 03:08:42 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)) ... For what that's worth.

Comment: Added the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `jsonObj` as an **array** not an object.  The first value in the array is your actual object.

try:

```
 var dateValue = new Date(jsonObj[0]["dateValue"]);
```

Or simplify your `jsonObj` value by making it the object, not a wrapping array.

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wyqzmhz1/

Answer (score 0):

Your `jsonObj` is an array - you should thus take the first item

```js
var jsonObj = [{
dateValue : "2016-11-04T08:08:42.5780021+00:00"
}];

var dateValue = new Date(jsonObj[0]["dateValue"]);
console.log(dateValue);
```